# Why can't I get past sign in on my php form? Session issue maybe?

Tags: php, session

I have my site hosted on collegeknowledge.ie - and it works fully on my localhost. Anyone can go to that link and sign up and they'll successfully be written to the database. My signin code works on my localhost and the session starts, however on my hosted site it just remains at signin.php even though the login credentials are correct. There are no errors!

Here is my code for signin:

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once 'dbconnect.php';

if (isset($_SESSION['userSession'])!="") {
    header("Location: home.php");
    exit;
}

if (isset($_POST['btn-login'])) {

    $email = strip_tags($_POST['email']);
    $password = strip_tags($_POST['password']);

    $email = $DBcon->real_escape_string($email);
    $password = $DBcon->real_escape_string($password);

    $query = $DBcon->query("SELECT user_id, email, password FROM users WHERE email='$email'");
    $row=$query->fetch_array();

    $count = $query->num_rows; // if email/password are correct returns must be 1 row

    if (password_verify($password, $row['password']) && $count==1) {
        $_SESSION['userSession'] = $row['user_id'];
        header("Location: home.php");
    } else {
        $msg = "<div class='alert alert-danger'>
                    <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign'></span> &nbsp; Invalid Username or Password !
                </div>";
    }
    $DBcon->close();
}
?>
```

Any reason why that wouldn't direct me to home.php on my hosted site even though it works fine on my localhost?

I have ensured that the session is started in home.php also.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the only problem of you code but 
isset() returns a boolean. It will result on an always true condiftion in the first 'if'.

Use:
`if (!isset($_SESSION['userSession']))`

Instead of:
`if (isset($_SESSION['userSession'])!="")`

Comment: Try `!empty();`

Comment: @Akintunde007 where should I put that "!empty();"?